# requestpermission dialog is not showing up when requesting to grant permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I'm asking for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission but no dialog is showing up.

Here's my code:

```
if (!checkPermissions()) {
    requestPermissions();
} else {
    getLastLocation();
}
```

Here's `requestPermission()`:

```
private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setMessage("Location permission is needed in order to show your current location");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting `08-31 13:02:25.067 8231-8231/com.appName.app/com.appName.app.MainActivity: Requesting permission` printed out but no dialog to ask permission is showing up.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the silly mistake.

I figured out the problem. I forgot to add `<uses-permission>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<manifest>` tag did the job.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                    {permission}, 123);

        }
```

now handle permisiion result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_GPS_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            Toast.makeText(this, "location_permission_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "location_permission_not_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**don't forget to add this permission in manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```